# How to create a WPF Storyboard in C# instead of XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this Xaml code which I want to convert into c# :

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sb_hr">
    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="56,48,0,0"/>
        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="400,48,0,0"/>
    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It is easy to create that storyboard in code. Someone can add value if you explain why you want to have this storyboard created in C# instead of XAML?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
EasingThicknessKeyFrame estf1 = new EasingThicknessKeyFrame();
estf1.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1));
estf1.Value = new Thickness(56, 48, 0, 0);
EasingThicknessKeyFrame estf2 = new EasingThicknessKeyFrame();
estf2.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1));
estf2.Value = new Thickness(400, 48, 0, 0);

ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames th = new ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
th.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, FrameworkElement.MarginProperty);
th.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, ellipse);
th.KeyFrames.Add(estf1);
th.KeyFrames.Add(estf2);
```